# Learning how to make functions in R - Distance Formula

Tags: r, function

I'm learning how to write functions in R and I thought it'd be good practice to write a function for the distance formula. What's really throwing me off is that your function parameters are coordinates rather than a singular number.

A gentle refresher for the distance formula:

```
d = sqrt((x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2)
```

This is what I've tried (and ultimately failed) so far. I have no idea where to start so any hints would be greatly appreciated. I've tried so many different combinations for p1 and p2 but I really don't know what to do.

```
p1 = c("x_1", "y_1")
p2 = c("x_2", "y_2")

find_distance <- function(p1, p2) {
  sqrt(("x_2" - "x_2")^2 + ("y_2" - "y_1")^2)
}
```

Comment: you just need to reference you values inside of `sqrt()` in terms of p1 and p2. ie `sqrt( ( p2[1] - p1[1] )^2 - ( p2[2] - p1[2] )^2)`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `p1` and `p2` into your function, but are not using them.

Also, your `x_1`, and `x_2` are elements of your `p1` and `p2` vectors, so you need to access those individual elements, rather than use the whole vector.

Take, for example

```
p1 <- c(1, 2)
p2 <- c(3, 4)
```

Then `x_1` is therefore

```
p1[1]
# [1]
```

and `x_2` is

```
p1[2]
# [2]
```

So we can now use the `p` values inside the function

```
find_distance <- function(p1, p2){
    res <- sqrt((p2[1] - p1[1])^2 + (p2[2] - p1[2])^2)
    return(res)
}

find_distance(p1, p2)
# [1] 2.828427
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 <- c(1, 2)
x2 <- c(3, 4)

my_distance_func <- function(p1, p2) {
  if (length(p1) != length(p2)) stop("p1 and p2 must be equi-length")
  return(sqrt(sum( (p1-p2)^2 )))
}

my_distance_func(x1, x2)
```

This code is vectorized and will scale to n-dimensional vectors `p1`, `p2`